# Is it legal to use memset() function on `const` array?

Tags: c, arrays, constants, memset

In the following code, elements of the `const` array are cleared by the `memset` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    printf("%d %d %d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it legal to use `memset` on `const` array?

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you a warning that arg1 to memset has a const mismatch.

Comment: You answered your own question !!

Comment: @SumitTrehan and?

Comment: There are already dozens of questions about modifying a const object, we don't need a new one for each possible modification function. Are you going to ask about `strncpy` onto a const char array next?

Comment: @M.M can you find a proper duplicate? if so please close.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b that is _if_ you read the warnings. lost of people consider that noise :)

Comment: why `const int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};` and not `const int a[] = {1, 2, 3};` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "lost of people consider that noise" that's their own damn problem and they are responsible for fixing it themselves.

Comment: @rsp you should operate your compiler in standard-conforming mode. There is no sense in running the compiler in non-standard mode and then trying to use passages from the standard to explain the behaviour

Comment: @rsp let me inyroduce you to some compiler flags. @rspthis is `-Wall -Werror`. `-Wall -Werror` this is @rsp. Hope you will be friends.

Comment: Good. Read them.

Comment: this is a self-answered question. It's ballsy to do that in C, but I suppose OP knows that the operation is illegal.

Comment: GCC generates diagnostics in `-pedantic` mode already for the constraint violation as the `const int *` is assigned to non-const `void *`. You need an *explicit cast here*. It is legal to explicitly cast `const int *` to `void *`, but it is not legal then to change anything through that pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**.

Do not attempt to modify the contents of the array declared as `const`, otherwise result is **undefined behavior**.

In that example, the elements of the `const int a[3];` are filled by the call to `memset` which is generated warning because the `memset` function takes a (non-const) pointer to void, the compiler must implicitly cast away `const`.

**C11 6.7.3 Type qualifiers:**

**Footnote 132:**

> **The implementation may place a `const` object that is not `volatile` in a
>   read-only region of storage**. Moreover, the implementation need not
>   allocate storage for such an object if its address is never used.

Comment: The quoted passages are irrelevant as the code contains a constraint violation